# getting error in cmd on appletviewer

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
public class MyApplet extends Applet{

}
```

This my txt code for applet:

```
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width="300" height="200"></applet>
```

I'm getting this error while running on cmd prompt.

[i/o error in appletviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tmpz.png)

Comment: Show the error in your question, not just as a screenshot, please.

Comment: Sir, this is the error "I/O exception while reading: C:\applet\Home.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)".

Comment: Does the file exist at the specified location?

Comment: yes Sir, the file is at same location where .class file is present.